# TASM output into file issues

Tags: assembly, tasm

I was honestly hoping to figure the problem out without needing to ask here, but I simply am unable to figure out the problem.

The program is to take input from a file, check if it's a palindrome and then output "This is a palindrome" or "This is not a palindrome" into a different file. Via debugger, I can see that the program reads the line from the file correctly and it checks if it's a palindrome correctly...at least, for the first line. After that it trips a JC that takes it to the end of the program ahead of time. I tried commenting out the JC, but then it just jumps to _end via end-of-file. That gets commented out? The program loops endlessly.

Provided below is the code in question. Be forewarned that it is quite long and a bit of a mess. I bolded the line in question that is currently, at least I believe, is causing the trouble.

NOTE: I noticed that the bolding doesn't work. Look for the line with two **'s on both sides. It's the best I can do.

```
.model small
.stack 100H
.data

len equ 2000

about       db 'Programa iesko palindromu nuskaitytoje eiluteje arba faile.',13,10,9,'2uzdasm.exe [/?] destinationFile [ - | sourceFile1 [sourceFile2] [...] ]',13,10,13,10,9,'/? - pagalba',13,10,'$'

err_source      db 'Source failo nepavyko atidaryti skaitymui',13,10,'$'
err_destination     db 'Destination failo nepavyko atidaryti rasymui',13,10,'$'
err_length      db 'Length of line is too short',13,10,'$'
not_palindrome  db 'The line is not a palindrome',13,10,'$'
palindrome      db 'The line is a palindrome',13,10,'$ '

sourceF     db 24 dup (0)
sourceFHandle   dw ?

destF       db 24 dup (0)
destFHandle     dw ?

buffer      db len dup (?)
buffer_offset dw 0
buffer_len dw 0
currentline       db len dup (?)
currentline_offset dw 0
is_pal  db 0
is_not_pal db 0

simbolis    db ?

EOF db, 0

.code

START:
mov ax, @data
mov es, ax

mov si, 81h

call space_skip

 mov    al, byte ptr ds:[si]    ; nuskaityt simboli
 cmp    al, 13          ; ner parametru, tai tada
 jne    _1
 jmp    help            ; pagalba

_1:

;; ar /? yra
 mov    ax, word ptr ds:[si]
 cmp    ax, 3F2Fh           ; jei nuskaityta "/?" - 3F = '?'; 2F = '/'
 jne    _2
 jmp    help                    ; rastas "/?", vadinasi reikia isvesti pagalba


_2:

;; destination failo pavadinimas
 lea    di, destF
 call   read_filename       ; perkelti is parametro i eilute
 cmp    byte ptr es:[destF], '$' ; jei nieko nenuskaite
 jne    _3
 jmp    help

_3:

;; source failo pavadinimas
 lea    di, sourceF
 call   read_filename       ; perkelti is parametro i eilute

 push   ds
 push   si

 mov    ax, @data
 mov    ds, ax

;; rasymui
 mov    dx, offset destF    ; ikelti i dx destF - failo pavadinima
 mov    ah, 3ch         ; isvalo/sukuria faila - komandos kodas
 mov    cx, 0           ; normal - no attributes
 int    21h         ; INT 21h / AH= 3Ch - create or truncate file.
                ;   Jei nebus isvalytas - tai perrasines senaji,
                ;   t.y. jei pries tai buves failas ilgesnis - like simboliai isliks.
 jnc    _4          ; CF set on error AX = error code.
 jmp    err_dest

_4:
 mov    ah, 3dh         ; atidaro faila - komandos kodas
 mov    al, 1           ; rasymui
 int    21h         ; INT 21h / AH= 3Dh - open existing file.
 jnc    _5          ; CF set on error AX = error code.
 jmp    err_dest

_5:
 mov    destFHandle, ax     ; issaugom handle

 jmp    startConverting

readSourceFile:
 pop    si
 pop    ds

;; source failo pavadinimas
 lea    di, sourceF
 call   read_filename       ; perkelti is parametro i eilute

 push   ds
 push   si

 mov    ax, @data
 mov    ds, ax

 cmp    byte ptr ds:[sourceF], '$' ; jei nieko nenuskaite
 jne    startConverting
 jmp    closeF

startConverting:
 ;; atidarom
 cmp    byte ptr ds:[sourceF], '$' ; jei nieko nenuskaite
 jne    source_from_file

 mov    sourceFHandle, 0
 jmp    skaitom

source_from_file:
 mov    dx, offset sourceF  ; failo pavadinimas
 mov    ah, 3dh                 ; atidaro faila - komandos kodas
 mov    al, 0                   ; 0 - reading, 1-writing, 2-abu
 int    21h         ; INT 21h / AH= 3Dh - open existing file
 jc err_sourc       ; CF set on error AX = error code.
 mov    sourceFHandle, ax   ; issaugojam filehandle

skaitom:

 mov    cx, ax              ; bytes actually read
 cmp    ax, 0           ; jei nenuskaite
 jne    _6          ; tai ne pabaiga

 mov    bx, sourceFHandle   ; pabaiga skaitomo failo
 mov    ah, 3eh         ; uzdaryti
 int    21h
 jmp    readSourceFile      ; atidaryti kita skaitoma faila, jei yra

_6:
 mov    si, offset buffer   ; skaitoma is cia
 mov    bx, destFHandle     ; rasoma i cia

 cmp    sourceFHandle, 0
 jne    _7
 cmp    byte ptr ds:[si], 13
 je closeF

 _7:
 push   cx          ; save big loop CX

atrenka:
 ;lodsb                 ; Load byte at address DS:(E)SI into AL
 push   cx          ; pasidedam cx
 call copy_line
 ;cmp EOF, 1
 ;je _end
 call is_pol
 mov    ah, 40h         ; INT 21h / AH= 40h - write to file
 int    21h
 pop    cx
 **jc   help**          ; CF set on error; AX = error code.**
 loop   atrenka

 pop    cx
 loop   skaitom

help:
 mov    ax, @data
 mov    ds, ax

 mov    dx, offset about         
 mov    ah, 09h
 int    21h

 jmp    _end

closeF:
 ;; uzdaryti dest
 mov    ah, 3eh         ; uzdaryti
 mov    bx, destFHandle
 int    21h

_end:
 mov    ax, 4c00h
 int    21h  

err_sourc:
 mov    ax, @data
 mov    ds, ax

 mov    dx, offset err_source        
 mov    ah, 09h
 int    21h

 mov    dx, offset sourceF
 int    21h

 mov    ax, 4c01h
 int    21h  

err_dest:
 mov    ax, @data
 mov    ds, ax

 mov    dx, offset err_destination         
 mov    ah, 09h
 int    21h

 mov    dx, offset destF
 int    21h

 mov    ax, 4c02h
 int    21h  

space_skip PROC near

space_skip_loop:
 cmp byte ptr ds:[si], ' '
 jne space_skip_end
 inc si
 jmp space_skip_loop
space_skip_end:
 ret

space_skip ENDP

copy_line PROC near
 push si
 mov currentline_offset, 0

copy_line_copy:
 mov ax, buffer_len
 ;cmp buffer_len, 6
 ;jl copy_line_error
 cmp buffer_offset, ax
 jl copy_line_tesk

 mov buffer_offset, 0
 mov    bx, sourceFHandle
 mov    dx, offset buffer       ; address of buffer in dx
 mov    cx, len                 ; kiek baitu nuskaitysim
 mov    ah, 3fh             ; function 3Fh - read from file
 int    21h
 ;jc error
 mov EOF, 1
 cmp ax, 0
 je copy_line_end
 mov EOF, 0
 mov buffer_len, ax

copy_line_tesk:
 mov si, offset buffer
 add si, buffer_offset
 mov al, byte ptr ds:[si]


 mov si, offset currentline
 add si, currentline_offset
 mov byte ptr ds:[si], al
 ;jmp copy_line_compare

 inc currentline_offset
 inc buffer_offset
 cmp ax, 13
 jne copy_line_copy

;copy_line_error:
 ;mov   ax, @data
 ;mov   ds, ax

 ;mov   dx, offset err_length        
 ;mov   ah, 09h
 ;int   21h

copy_line_end:
 pop si
 ret
copy_line ENDP

is_pol PROC near
 mov si, offset currentline
 mov di, offset currentline
 add di, currentline_offset

comparesi:
 cmp byte ptr [si], 'a' ;si = start, di = end, ascii table for comparisons, inc and dec si, di.
 jl notsmallsi
 cmp byte ptr [si], 'z'
 jg notsymbolsi
 jmp comparedi
notsmallsi:
 cmp byte ptr [si], 'A'
 jl notlargesi
 cmp byte ptr [si], 'Z'
 jg notsymbolsi
 jmp comparedi
notlargesi:
 cmp byte ptr [si], '0'
 jl notsymbolsi
 cmp byte ptr [si], '9'
 jg notsymbolsi
 jmp comparedi
notsymbolsi:
 inc si
 jmp comparesi
comparedi:
 cmp byte ptr [di], 'a'
 jl notsmalldi
 cmp byte ptr [di], 'z'
 jg notsymboldi
 jmp compare
notsmalldi:
 cmp byte ptr [di], 'A'
 jl notlargedi
 cmp byte ptr [di], 'Z'
 jg notsymboldi
 jmp compare
notlargedi:
 cmp byte ptr [di], '0'
 jl notsymboldi
 cmp byte ptr [di], '9'
 jg notsymboldi
 jmp compare
notsymboldi:
 dec di
 jmp comparedi
compare:
 mov al, byte ptr [di]
 cmp byte ptr [si], al
 jne no_palindrome
 inc si
 dec di
 cmp si, di
 jge is_palindrome
 jmp comparesi

no_palindrome:
 lea dx, not_palindrome
 mov cx, 30
 ret

is_palindrome:
 lea dx, palindrome
 mov cx, 30
 ret
is_pol ENDP

read_filename PROC near

 push   ax
 call   space_skip
read_filename_start:
 cmp    byte ptr ds:[si], 13    ; jei nera parametru
 je read_filename_end   ; tai taip, tai baigtas failo vedimas
 cmp    byte ptr ds:[si], ' '   ; jei tarpas
 jne    read_filename_next  ; tai praleisti visus tarpus, ir sokti prie kito parametro
read_filename_end:
 mov    al, '$'         ; irasyti '$' gale
 stosb                           ; Store AL at address ES:(E)DI, di = di + 1
 pop    ax
 ret
read_filename_next:
 lodsb              ; uzkrauna kita simboli
 stosb                           ; Store AL at address ES:(E)DI, di =     di     + 1
 jmp read_filename_start

read_filename ENDP

end START
```

Comment: asm code is *much* easier to read when you indent the instructions one level more than the labels.  (SO code formatting works better when everything is a space, rather than a mix of tab and space characters.  If your original code wasn't an ugly wall of code, that may be what happened.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Duly noted. Hopefully now the formatting is better.

Comment: I noticed that, if I change the mentioned line from jc to jnc, then it actually does something: Print out one line (in my case I have 3 lines to test, it prints out the middle one), spew a bit of garbage code on the next line and then trip the other jc. So, progress, but not much...

Comment: Why is your code setting `ds` in multiple places, instead of just setting `ds` once at the start?  It looks like a mess to me.  I haven't written 16bit code, but I think I understand how it works.  http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_21.html says `int 21h, ax=40h` that `ds:dx` is the pointer to the buffer to be written.  There's no comment or anything around the `jc help` to indicate that the function call in that loop returns anything in `dx`, instead of the usual ABI of `eax` for return values.  (Sorry, I'm not in the mood to read a big 16bit program and fully debug it. :/)

Answer (score 2):

I didn't have the time to look at the whole program since it's a bit lengthy, but here are 2 observations that might help you correct the code:

```
 jnc    _4          ; CF set on error AX = error code.
 jmp    err_dest

_4:
 mov    ah, 3dh         ; atidaro faila - komandos kodas
```

When the destination got created succesfully is was also opened and you got a handle from DOS. Either don't re-open in (as you now do at the label *_4*) OR close the handle prior to opening it again.

```
skaitom:

 mov    cx, ax              ; bytes actually read
```

Here at *skaitom* the AX register holds a handle but at some point later in the program you use this value as a loop counter! That can't be correct.